# I can't seem to install react-alert

Tags: reactjs

After inputting npm i react-alert and npm i react-alert-bootstrap-template on my terminal, there seems to be an error which I can't comprehend.
[image: react-alert error]

here is my .json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried uninstalling and downgrading react but I got a different error. Hence I deleted the folder and created a new one. Please help me with my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --save react-alert react-alert-template-basic` or just `npm install --save react-alert-template-basic`?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be because the package is only compatible with the older version of the react. You can try either,

```
npm i react-alert --legacy-peer-deps
npm i react-alert-bootstrap-template --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or if it din't work. You can also try,

```
npm i react-alert --force
npm i react-alert-bootstrap-template --force
```

Answer (score 0):

make these changes in your package.json file and then try to run the command.

"react": "^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.0"

Comment: Hi, can you please explain in your answer why are these changes necessary?

Answer (score 0):

it seems react alert related packages are not upgraded to work with new version of react currently which is `18.2.0` so either you have to install you package with `--force` flag for example `npm i react-alert --force` or you have to modify your `package.josn` file as this `"react": "^16.2.0",`

Answer (score 0):

Two packages named `react-alert` & `react-alert-template-basic` are not compatible with ReactJS version 18. So, you need to append addition flag which is `--legacy-peer-deeps` to the installation command. Such as:

```
npm i react-alert --legacy-peer-deps 
npm i react-alert-template-basic --legacy-peer-deps
```

This worked for me.